# How can I export data from Google App Engine High Replication datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am looking into using Google App Engine for a project and would like make sure I have a way to export all my data if I ever decide to leave GAE (or GAE shuts down).

Everything I search about exporting data from GAE points to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata. However, that page contains this note:

> Note: This document applies to apps that use the master/slave
>   datastore. If your app uses the High Replication datastore, it is
>   possible to copy data from the app, but Google does not currently
>   support this use case. If you attempt to copy from a High Replication
>   datastore, you'll see a high_replication_warning error in the Admin
>   Console, and the downloaded data might not include recently saved
>   entities.

The problem is that recently the master/slave datastore was recently deprecated in favor of the High Replication datastore. I understand that the master/slave datastore is still supported for a little while, but I don't feel comfortable using something that has officially been deprecated and is on its way out. So that leaves me with the High Replication datastore and the only way it seems to export the data is the method above that is not officially supported (and thus does not provide me with a guarantee that I can get my data out).

Is there any other (officially supported) way of exporting data from the High Replication datastore? I don't feel comfortable using Google App Engine if it means my data could be locked in there forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure a builtin called [remote_api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Builtin_Handlers). [This article](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) has all the information and guide you need to be able to download all your data today and in the future.

Comment: The problem is that as I mentioned, that method is not officially supported for High Replication datastore which is what I will be using.

Comment: I believe it works for your porpuse. HRD is a distributed system, that's why if you attemp to download your data, it may not be a fresh copy. But if you plan to migrate, it's almost probably that you previously disabled writes. So you will have a safe time to let the HRD replicates all changes.

Answer (score 2):

It took me quite a long time to setup the download of data from GAE as the documentation is not as clear as it should be.

If you extracting data from a Unix server, you maybe could reuse the script below.

Also, if you do not provide the "config_file" parameter, it will extract all your data for this kind but in a proprietary format which can only be used for restoring data afterwards.

```
#!/bin/sh
#------------------------------------------------------------------
#-- Param 1 : Namespace
#-- Param 2 : Kind (table id)
#-- Param 3 : Directory in which the csv file should be stored
#-- Param 4 : output file name
#------------------------------------------------------------------
appcfg.py download_data --secure --email=$BACKUP_USERID --        config_file=configClientExtract.yml --filename=$3/$4.csv --kind=$2 --url=$BACKUP_WEBSITE/remote_api --namespace=$1 --passin <<-EOF $BACKUP_PASSWORD EOF
```

Comment: What is configClientExtract.yml (--config_file) and --url? Yes the help page doesn't describe what the config file or url endpoint accept

Answer (score 1):

Currently app engine datastore supports another option also. Data backup provision can be used to copy selected data into blob store or google cloud storage. This function is available under datastore admin area in app engine console. If required, the backed up data can then be downloaded from the blob viewer or cloud storage. For doing the backup for high replication datastore, it is recommended that datastore writes are disabled before taking the backup.