# How am I supposed to back up the data that my app is storing in the datastore of GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, database-backups

I have a form application deployed on Google App Engine. It also uses the High Replication Data-store. I wish to backup the data. I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209091/how-can-i-export-data-from-google-app-engine-high-replication-datastore) link but the in the answer the link is not really helping me ([answer link](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata)).

Other answers are using linux and not windows environments so again I am having trouble. Does anyone know about some tutorial that explains each step for downloading data form the GAE Data-store ?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following docs will help you to setup Backup/Restore, Copy, and Delete google appnengine data: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin

Also refer Scheduled Backups: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scheduled_backups

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help.

1. Go to Datastore Admin Select your entities and create backup.
2. Go to Blob Viewer click to file name created in step 1, and download.

Regards.