# How do I clone a website that is hosted on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a friend's website hosted on Google App Engine and he wants a some changes to be done. He wants to download the assets from there and build it from scratch into a different host provider. Thing is, when I enter in the Google App Engine Dashboard I find it so hard to export/download anything. All looks so messy. I can't even find the index.html and css files. Any answers would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download an application's source code by running appcfg.py with the download_app action in the Python SDK command-line tool:

```
appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>
```

Only the developer who uploaded the code and the application owner(s) can download it. But you can be added as admin by the current account holder and then your credentials will work on the command line.

It's possible downloading of source-code has been permanently disabled. This action is irreversible. After you prohibit code download, there is no way to re-enable this feature.

See this page for more: [Python Downloading source code](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Python_Downloading_source_code)

Instructions above for python version. For Java look [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_an_Application). Others, start [here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/)

Comment: @appostolis GAE is not regular hosting, don't think of it as easy as FTP.

Comment: alright, i have downloaded the SDK for Python and I'll go with the documentation. Thanks for the links )

Comment: Well, I think it's not that simple. I found out that my app uses High Replication datastore which according to this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Python_Downloading_and_uploading_all_data I can't download the data I want. Am I missing something here? :D

Comment: I think it'll be ok anyway. I read that as saying that the downloaded data might not include recently saved entities, rather the it not being possible at all. Tried it? Or you could write a simple modification to the code itself to read out the data in some way from the datastore in a usable format, depends how much there is really for how you'd do that. see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209091/how-can-i-export-data-from-google-app-engine-high-replication-datastore and suggest you disable writes in the admin panel in any case before an export attempt.

Comment: Sorry for the noobish questions, but, when I click the SDK Console in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher I get the localhost server like: http://localhost:8000/instances. So, there, I have no clue what I am doing. I wanted to run this: appcfg.py download_app -A <your_app_id> -V <your_app_version> <output-dir>.

Comment: It's a command line tool, not available (AFAIK) from the GUI you seem to be talking about. So drop into the command line, find where your appcfg.py lives and run it from there instead.